# Changing html renderer in Wanderlust

Tags: email, wanderlust

I would like to modify how mime/html entities are transformed to text in Wanderlust. At the very least removing background colors and excessive spacing. Is there any simple way to do so?

Comment: Did you mean "mime" instead of "mine". If so, please edit. Thx.

Comment: There is nothing simple about tweaking Wanderlust or about modifying the way in which w3m converts the html parts.  I have, however, successfully modified several components over the years and presently use a modified version of everything.  In general, I have spent several hours to a full day on each and every significant issue ..., but then again, I'm not a real programmer, just a hobby-ist .... `w3m-region` and `w3m-fonfify` look like a good place for you to start.  I have done quite a bit of modifying how `w3m-fontify-images` handles links and so forth ....

Comment: Thanks, @Drew Sorry for the typo. I was writing this on an iPad that insists on replacing my words without warning.

Answer (score 4):

Following @lawlist's idea of digging through the code, I have found one possible answer. It is not entirely satisfactory, but good enough for the emails I have received so far. This answer relies on using Emacs' Simple Html Renderer and removing all the fancy color rendering. It is a simple tweak

```
;; Rendering of messages using 'shr', Emacs' simple html
;; renderer, but without fancy coloring that distorts the
;; looks
(setq mime-view-text/html-previewer shr
      shr-use-fonts nil
      shr-use-colors nil)
```

I have not yet managed to display embedded images. I suppose this requires actual tweaking of code.

Edit: it seems embedded images as in  tags are shown, but not always when they are in attachments.